# How do I show a form only when data is loaded?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ado

I need some help on a thing that I can't resolve.

I've a Windows Form with a DataGridView who is populated with a large amount of data.
This data is stored in a SQL Server Database and retrieved by a simple piece of ADO.NET code.

I'm already using the BackGroundWorker class to perform this kind of operation but the form still freezes for 1-2 second.

Is there a way to delay the showing of the form? Like a show form only when all data in loaded? I've tried to make it not visible or to use Hide() and Show() method but still not have any results.

Comment: show us your worker code.

Comment: Hi Mo. Thank you for your answer.
The code of the BackGroundWorker is very simple.
I call a method who populate a bindinglist and set that to the DataSource of my DataGridView.

Comment: You probably don't want to wait until the data is loaded before you show the form. It will be less frustrating for the users to see an empty form that then gets populated, than for them to wonder why nothing is appearing on the screen.

Comment: Probably.
The perfect solution, for my purpose, is a thing like that: press button, initialize form, populate form/datagridview with loaded data, show form. It took around 2 second. In that time I would like to show a "Please wait... form in a new thread.

Comment: Why a large amount of data? Why not a limited set based on some search criterion?

Comment: using progressbar for upto load data

Comment: I can't retrieve a small amount of that.
Data are a list of 1200 answers stored in a 8 columns SQL table.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a easy work-around.
Change the modifiers of the BackGroundWorker to public. 
Create the instance of the form, run Form.CreateControl() and call the BackGroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync() method.
In the DoWork event I put: data retrieving and population of the controls (DataGridView, combobox and textbox).
In the RunWorkerCompleted just the Form.Show() method.
That's all. Is this a nice solution?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `InitializeComponent();` from constructor of your form and call this method when data has loaded

Comment: I can't do that because I need all the controls of my form.

Comment: @MoPatel Random answer!.. :)

Comment: @MoPatel 
I think no significant delay of 1-2 seconds to load the the form. However, this solution is not appropriate because the  controls are required.

Comment: @Dr_klo I think nobody knows the answers. I suppose to be a easy work. Try to explain it one more time: click on a button -> load data on the form (populate combobox, textbox, datagridview - around 2sec) -> show form. That's all.

Comment: @Nicola previously i thought that form are frozen while loading with data together. thanks for explanation.